# bash string not matching in if clause

Tags: bash

I am running into a strange issue. In the below piece of code the echo statement works fine and in success.txt I get `b4 running=false with RUNNING:false` which means $RUNNING = false.

But it is not going into the `if` block.

```
echo "b4 running=false with RUNNING:"$RUNNING >> /tmp/success.txt
if [[ $RUNNING == "false" ]]; then
  echo "in running=false" >> /tmp/success.txt    
  exit 2
fi
```

I also tried

```
if [[ $RUNNING == false ]]; then
  echo "in running=false" >> /tmp/success.txt    
  exit 2
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then
  echo "in running=false" >> /tmp/success.txt    
  exit 2
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == false]; then
  echo "in running=false" >> /tmp/success.txt    
  exit 2
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then
  echo "in running=false" >> /tmp/success.txt    
  exit 2
fi
```

None of these is working. I am sure I am missing something very small here.

Comment: Where are you setting `RUNNING` variable in the script you have? As such your original attempt works fine. Can you do `echo "$RUNNING"` and paste it here?

Comment: Right before the if block I have an echo statement which I am piping to .txt file `echo "b4 running=false with RUNNING:"$RUNNING >> /tmp/success.txt` and I can see `b4 running=false with RUNNING:false` in the .txt file correctly. The next line  after this is `if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then` there is nothing in between both these lines.

Answer (score 1):

When I try

```
RUNNING=false
if [[ $RUNNING == false ]]; then
    echo 1
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then
    echo 2
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == false]; then
    echo 3
fi

if [ "$RUNNING" == "false" ]; then
    echo 4
fi
```

I get

> 1
>   2
>   /tmp/a.sh: line 10: [: missing `]'
>   4

Fixing the third one from

```
if [ "$RUNNING" == false]; then
```

to

```
if [ "$RUNNING" == false ]; then
```

Note the additional space between `false` and `]`.
Now I get

> 1
>   2
>   3
>   4

So all four are valid, *if* `$RUNNING` is `false`. The difference might be a trailing new line character or some white space around `false`/`$RUNNING`, if the value is captured from the output of some command.

See [Conditional Constructs](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Conditional-Constructs) and [Bash Conditional Expressions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Bash-Conditional-Expressions) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried the following:

```
if [ $RUNNING == "false" ]; then
    echo "test"
fi
```

That seems to work for me.

Cheers

Comment: Strange thing is when I run the script using `./script.sh` it works fine but I have set this script to be run in crontab and that's where it fails. I have used `crontab -e` and `*/2 * * * * /root/todo-api/workspace/docker.sh` in it.

Comment: @love2code The script executes using different environments when you run it as you and when you run it in crontab. What does your shebang look like?

Comment: `/bin/bash` my shebang. I have just added `#!/bin/bash` as first line of my script. Let's see if this helps